# sbt not recognizing test

Tags: testing, sbt, junit4

I am having difficulties getting sbt (version 0.12.1) to recognize any tests in src/test/scala.

I have tried both JUnit style tests and scalatest style tests but to no avial

To make things simple

- I have moved my tests to the root package (src/test/scala)
- I have included both org.scalatest and junit-interface in my build.sbt 
  libraryDependencies ++= List(
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.8" % "test",
    "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.8" % "test->default"
    )
- I have made the tests as simple as possible:
- scalatest example

  import org.scalatest.FunSuite
  import scala.collection.mutable.Stack

  class ExampleSuite extends FunSuite {

  test("math still works") {
      assert(1+1 == 2)
    }
  }
- junit test example:
  import org.junit.Assert._
  import org.junit.Test

  class SimpleTest {

  @Test
    def testPass() {
      assertEquals(1+1, 2)
    }

  }
- my test structure is:
  src/test/scala

  ├── FunSuiteExample.scala

  └── SimpleTest.scala

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the console output from `sbt test`?

Answer (score 3):

based on instructions at:

https://github.com/szeiger/junit-interface

modfied `build.sbt`

- removed `"junit" % "junit" % "4.10" % "test"` from build.sbt
- added `"com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % "test"`

put test in src/test/scala

```
import org.junit._
import org.junit.Assert._


class SimpleTeset {

  @Test
  def testTrue() {
    assertEquals(1+1, 2)
  }
}
```

Comment: Works with SBT 1.1.4